# How to request a new facebook token

Tags: android, facebook

My Android app uses Facebook for authentication and everything is working fine for most of the users. But some of them are getting this error below when I execute `com.facebook.Request#newMeRequest` after the authentication:

```
error_code: 190
error_type: OAuthException
error_message: Error validating access token: The session has been invalidated because the user has changed the password.
```

I understand that I need to request a new access token, but I couldn't find how to do that.
Someone can help me?

Here's my code:

```
private Session.StatusCallback statusCallback = new StatusCallback() {
    @Override
    public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        if (state == SessionState.OPENED) {
            authenticate();

        } else if (state == SessionState.CLOSED_LOGIN_FAILED) {
            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, exception.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
};

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();

    if (!session.isOpened() && !session.isClosed()) {
        Session.OpenRequest request = new Session.OpenRequest(this);
        request.setPermissions("basic_info", "email");
        request.setCallback(statusCallback);
        session.openForRead(request);

    } else {
        Session.openActiveSession(this, true, statusCallback);
    }
}

private void authenticate() {
    final Session session = Session.getActiveSession();

    if (session.isOpened()) {
        Request.newMeRequest(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                FacebookRequestError error = response.getError();

                if (error != null) {
                    // OAuthException is happening here
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, error.getErrorMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return;
                }

                String facebookToken = session.getAccessToken();

                // use fb info ...
            }
        }).executeAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: So this is happening right after the initial authentication. I've read that this might be related to "offline_access" being deprecated, so make sure you're not using that. If that's not the case this might be a bug from Facebook's side.

Comment: I'm not using 'offline_access', so there is nothing that I can do about this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the Users login to your aplication again, as described in https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/#expiredtokens

> If the access token becomes invalid, the solution is to have the person
>   log in again, at which point you will be able to make API calls on
>   their behalf once more. The login flow your app uses for new people
>   should determine which method you need to adopt.

Comment: Even if the user has just logged for the first time?